# How to implement Short Polling method in Next 13 Server Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13, polling

I am currently making an API fetching every 3000ms using setInterval method, I noticed the component doesn't re-render with latest data. Below is the code block

```
const Home = async () => {
 let customers = await getCustomers();
 setInterval(async () => customers = await getCustomers(), 3000);
}

return (
  customers.length > 0 &&
  <>
   {
      customers.map(customer => (<p>{customer.name}</p>)
   }
  </>
)
```

Currently the page doesn't update itself unless I manually refresh the page which is bad in UX perspective. Any seniors have any idea on how to make proper polling to backend using server components?

I did trying normal console logging, which it works when I replace the code expression inside setInterval method with console logs. I understand if it's client component it re-render the whole component using useEffect() but since this is the main root component, it has to be the server component by default in Next 13.

Comment: you can turn it into client component, no?

Comment: I could, but it requires to change the whole architecture of the app I'm building. That's why I'm looking for easier solution which to remain the current structure and yet find a workaround using short polling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Server Components were not designed to maintain a connection with client, therefore, to resolve this issue, you have to convert your Server Component to a Client Component.

In your case, I would maintain that component removing the setInterval and provide make another client component that uses React Query or SWR.

I would pass the initial data to the query method and later revalidating the data with those libraries.

https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/initial-query-data
https://swr.vercel.app/docs/with-nextjs#pre-rendering-with-default-data

There you can find some examples of how to implement the feature with both React Query and SWR.

Comment: Long polling, server-side-events...?